# How to turn off debugging for just dozer?

Tags: logging, dozer

Is there a way to turn off debug logging for just dozer? At least without having to increase it above the debug level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add:

```
log4j.logger.org.dozer=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters=ERROR
```

to your log4j.properties file.

Comment: Hi, I have this case - I am using Hadoop where log4j properties are read from cloud configuration log4j file I don't have permissions to edit, nor is a good solution to add dozer-specific conf in this file. Do you know for a way to do this in code - to set dozer log level to ERROR?